# Get-AzureAccount is not working in Az modules

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, azure-rm, az

**Get-AzureAccount** is not working in Az modules .It is giving below error :

```
Get-AzureAccount : The 'Get-AzureAccount' command was found in the module 'Azure', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module Azure'.
+     Get-AzureAccount | ForEach-Object { Remove-AzureAccount $_.ID -Fo ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-AzureAccount:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule
```

This Command was working in AzureRM modules as AzureRm is depricating , we need to change all commands to
Az modules.

Kindly Help!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, if the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To login to Azure With Az the command is:

```
Connect-AzAccount
```

Install PowerShell Core 7 and install Az
this way you can run Both AzureRm and Az

```
Uninstall-AzureRm

Find-Module -Name Az | Install-Module -AllowClobber
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have [Az module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-4.3.0) installed, you should use [Get-AzContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/get-azcontext?view=azps-4.3.0) instead of `Get-AzureAccount`.

And I see you also used `Remove-AzureAccount`, but in `Az module`, you should use [Remove-AzContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/remove-azcontext?view=azps-4.3.0) instead.

The sample code looks like below:

```
Get-AzContext | ForEach-Object { Remove-AzContext -Name $_.name -Force}
```